# Libgdx: не поддерживает ttf шрифты и цифры?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Скачал шрифт: comic-sans-ms.ttf.
добавил в gradle все необходимые [dependencies](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#freetypefont-gradle).
В assets закинул шрифт.
Создал метод:

```
   private void createFonts() {

    FileHandle fontFile = Gdx.files.internal("comic-sans-ms.ttf.ttf");
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(fontFile);
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 16;
    parameter.color.add(Color.BLACK);

    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);

    generator.dispose();
}

//в конструкторе   вызываю
  public GameScreen(final Drop gam) {
 createFonts();

}
```

В рендер вывожу переменную,которая увеличиваеют свое значение:

```
  font.getData();
    font.getColor();

    font.draw(game.batch, " " + game.dropsGatchered, 120, 470);
```

после запуска, на экране не отображается цифры (game.dropsGatchered).
Если не использовать шрифты,то стандартными шрифтами libgdx все отрисовывается.
Использовал эту [инструкцию](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype)

Comment: Рубрика глупых ответов: даже libgdx ненавидит Comic Sans

Comment: @ leon0399
а по поводу подключения и вывода на экран в синтаксисе нет проблем?

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте ещё прописать используемые символы, мне помогло

```
private final String FONT_CHARACTERS = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789][_!$%#@|\\/?-+=()*&.;,{}\"´`'<>";
```

и в коде

```
parameter.characters = FONT_CHARACTERS;
```